# How to check if two xarray objects have the same dimensions and coordinates (but not necessarily values)

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I have 2 xarray objects. I would like to check if these 2 arrays have the same dimensions and coordinates. But the two objects don't need to have the same values or meta data.

For example:

```
import xarray as xr

arr1_data = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
arr2_data = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]

arr1 = xr.DataArray(arr1_data, dims=["y", "x"], coords={"y": ["coord1", "coord2"]})
arr2 = xr.DataArray(arr2_data, dims=["y", "x"], coords={"y": ["coord1", "coord2"]})

compare_xarray_objects(arr1, arr2)  # Should return True
```

The `.dims` attribute returns a tuple, so it is easy to tell if dimensions are the same. But `.coords` attribute returns a `DataArrayCoordinates` object and I don't know how to compare a `DataArrayCoordinates` object with another one.

Comment: Will str(arr1.coords)==str(arr2.coords) work? Or use regex on these strings to go in more depth?

Comment: @Yadnesh Salvi that will only compare the parts of the cords which appear in the repr, which is almost always a small preview of the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

For cases like the one in your example where you're trying to compare *indexing* coordinates, simply use [`xr.align`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.align.html) with the `join='exact'` argument.

```py
xr.align(arr1, arr2, join='exact')  # will raise a ValueError if not aligned
```

If you're trying to also compare non-indexing coordinates, you could also use [`xr.testing.assert_equal`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.testing.assert_equal.html). This will check all coordinates, including those not in the dimension of the array (e.g. if you had another coordinate `z` indexed by `x` and `y`). However, it's a bit pickier than `xr.align`, as it requires the dimension ordering to be the same. If this were an issue, you could loop through the non-indexing coordinates and use this testing function to check equality for each coordinate.

Comment: xr.align only seems to compare coordinates that are common for both arr1 and arr2. For example, this does not raise an error if arr2 has an extra dimension that arr1 does not have.